# perl script which can upload image,crop it and make it clear throug imagemagick commands

Tags: centos7

i want to develop a Perl script on centos7 minimal which can easily get data(quadrants) of image from data base and according to those quadrant it can crop that image and save a new file of that cropped image.

Comment: Please give more detail. What do you mean by getting quadrants from a data base? Do you mean you want to split an image into 4 equal sized parts arranged 2x2 or just any quadrant. If so, see the ImageMagick -crop command at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop. The access to the database is not part of ImageMagick. So you would have to retrieve the image first.